# How can I debug a missing Facebook Like Button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, facebook-like

I'm trying to attach the *Like Button* and *Tweet Button* to a page using jQuery. The Tweet Button works just fine, but the Like Button won't appear. I don't know what's wrong, but worse yet, I don't get any errors or messages indicating a problem.

How can I get Facebook, Firebug, or anything to tell me what's missing, or throw appropriate errors?

Here is a [demonstration on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/btN89/).

Here is the full code for those of you who don't want to go to jsfiddle:

```
/**
 * Generate the container elements for social media stuff.
 */
$(function generateSocMedElements($) {
    var id = "socmed",
        $container,
        $fb_root,
        $fb_like,
        $tweet_button;
    if ($("#" + id).length <= 0) {
        $container = $(document.createElement("aside")).
            addClass("socmed").
            attr("id", id);
        $fb_root = $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "fb-root");
        $fb_like = $(document.createElement("div")).
            addClass("fb-like").
            attr("data-href", "example.org").
            attr("data-send", "false").
            attr("data-layout", "button_count").
            attr("data-width", 82).attr("data-show-faces", "false");
        $tweet_button = $(document.createElement("a")).
            addClass("twitter-share-button").
            attr("href", "//twitter.com/share").
            attr("data-count", "none").
            text("Tweet");
        $container.
            appendTo($("header").first()).
            append($fb_root).
            append($fb_like).
            append($tweet_button);
    }
});

/**
 * Load the script for the Facebook API.
 */
$(function loadFacebook($) {
    var id = "facebook-jssdk";
    if ($("#" + id).length <= 0) {
        $(document.createElement("script")).
            attr("id", id).
            attr("src", "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js").
            appendTo("head");
    }
});

/**
 * Load the script for the Twitter API.
 */
$(function loadTwitter($) {
    var id = 'twitterSdk';
    if ($("#" + id).length <= 0) {
        $(document.createElement("script")).
            attr("id", id).
            attr("src", "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js").
            appendTo("head");
    }
});
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with this code? As far as I can tell, you're trying to load the buttons dynamically... but you're using "#" and 'id' all over for selecting the elements, but also using "addClass." Are you trying to find the "Like" and "Tweet" links on the page and replace them with dynamically generated buttons?

Comment: in js fiddle it looks like the all.js is not being appended for some reason. I will keep playing with this for a bit and post back with any results.  I would suggest just using the iframe version of like button for now.

Comment: @CalebGray The Like and Tweet buttons should not exist when this script runs, but I threw in a check just in case it does. What should happen is that the Tweet and Like buttons should appear as the children of an `aside` element appended to the first `header` element on the page.

Comment: @ShawnECarter Yeah, I saw that too. But what's weirder is that Firebug still appears to recognize the script in its list of loaded scripts. Does the script delete itself for some cockamamy reason?

Comment: You should debug the missing facebook `like` button using the "Missing Facebook `Like` Button Debugger Add-On For Visual Studio 2010", of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ShawnsSpace/btN89/3/ i was able to get it to work by

1. adding div tag in header
2. wrapping generateSocMedElements() in a function and calling after page load.
3. used facebooks html5 script.

.  You will have to tweek this to get the desired look.

```
<header><h1>OH HAI I HAZ A HEADER</h1>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
</header>
```

---

```
/**
 * Load the script for the Facebook API.
 */

(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


/**
 * Load the script for the Twitter API.
 */
$(function loadTwitter($) {
    var id = 'twitterSdk';
    if ($("#" + id).length <= 0) {
        $(document.createElement("script")).
            attr("id", id).
            attr("src", "//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js").
            appendTo("head");
    }
});
function loadthis($){
$(function generateSocMedElements($) {
    var id = "socmed",
        $container,
        $fb_root,
        $fb_like,
        $tweet_button;
    if ($("#" + id).length <= 0) {
        $container = $(document.createElement("aside")).
            addClass("socmed").
            attr("id", id);
        $fb_root = $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "fb-root");
        $fb_like = $(document.createElement("div")).
            addClass("fb-like").
            attr("data-href", "example.org").
            attr("data-send", "false").
            attr("data-layout", "button_count").
            attr("data-width", 82).attr("data-show-faces", "false");
        $tweet_button = $(document.createElement("a")).
            addClass("twitter-share-button").
            attr("href", "//twitter.com/share").
            attr("data-count", "none").
            text("Tweet");
        $container.
            appendTo($("header").first()).
            append($fb_root).
            append($fb_like).
            append($tweet_button);
    }
});
}
loadthis($);
```